# Input type="file" set base64 image data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-canvas

I have a canvas and retrieve image data from it with help of `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`.

**Problem:** `<input type="file" />` wants filepath as `value` instead of base64 data.

**Question:** *How to send base64 image data to server with help of `<input type="file" />` WITHOUT saving them to local file system?*

**My workarounds:** Tried hidden input `<input type="file" />`, but server requires filename property

*Maybe that's possible to overcome this with XmlHttpRequest?*

Comment: Why do you need to convert base64 image to file input? You can simply send base64 string to the server, and then convert it to an image server-side.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev server is third party, I can't change it API.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess, this article can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks! Will play with it

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that helps! Thank you a lot!!!! You may create your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @VB_ It's and old question, but still relevant. I created that answer. Would be nice if you accept it for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Just create a hidden input element in your form. (notice the *type*)

```
<input type="hidden" name="myHiddenField">
```

Attach your data to the value of the element before submitting.

```
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.getElementsByName("myHiddenField")[0].setAttribute("value", imageData);
```

UPDATE

If your server demands to have the parameter "filename" in the submitted data, then include that string as the name of the `input` element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="filename"/>
```

This will trick the form to submit your data with the "filename" parameter included in it.

If you want to use `XMLHttpRequest` for this, following is a sample:

```
//Prepare data to be sent
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var params = "filename=" + imageData;

//Initiate the request
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();            
httpRequest.open('POST', 'test.php', true);

//Send proper headers
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

//Send your data
httpRequest.send(params);
```

Comment: unfortunatelly that doesn't work because server requires `filename` parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297565/submit-hidden-input-with-filename-parameter

Comment: The trick is that you can use name="filename" in the input element. I have updated my answer with this and also XMLHttpRequest method.

Comment: It's much easier to use name="filename" in your input tag than creating a whole new object just in place of a single element. Anyway - the way you like it. :)

Comment: If your server returns bad request to `<input type="hidden" name="filename">`, then you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I have problems because my base64 is bigger than 512kb so I get the image cut (my base64 is about 640kb), how could I do?

Comment: You mean you get a half-image by the method `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` ?

Comment: Trick in a trick in a trick. Welcome to the Web programming world.

Comment: Hi @Charlie  thanks for the great anwser. What if I want to send multiple `base64` images this way? then How can I distinguish what file name belongs to what hidden input?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FileReader, check examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: my image doesn't exists on local, only in-memory. Would it work?

Comment: I see, then you can just use XHR (XMLHttpRequest) to send the dataUrl to server

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer was not created, and I missed to have an easy to copy solution, I explored [@Yeldar Kurmangaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218692/yeldar-kurmangaliyev) comment, and then I coded a working example for future visitors.

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" accept="'image/png'" multiple="multiple" />
    
<script>
    //Function that converts a data64 png image to a Blob object
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI){
        var binary=atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var array=[];
        for(i=0;i<binary.length;i++){
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)],{type:'image/png'});
    }

    //Function that inserts an array of File objects inside a input type file, because HTMLInputElement.files cannot be setted directly
    function FileListItems(file_objects){
        new_input=new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData||new DataTransfer()
        for(i=0,size=file_objects.length;i<size;++i){
            new_input.items.add(file_objects[i]);
        }
        return new_input.files;
    }               

    //An image of a small square gray and white
    const data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII";
    //Create a Blob object
    blob=(dataURItoBlob(data));
    //Use the Blob to create a File Object
    file=new File([blob],"img.png",{type:"image/png",lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
    //Putting the File object inside an array because my input is multiple
    array_images=[file]; //You can add more File objects if your input is multiple too
    //Modify the input content to be submited
    input_images=document.querySelector("input#images")
    input_images.files=new FileListItems(array_images);
</script>
```